# Edit style/location of the captions of figures

Tags: floats, captions, article

Is there any way I can edit the style of a caption of a figure?

I'm using figure environments in the article document-class, and something that I've always wanted to change is the way the captions of figures are displayed. In particular, I wanted to make the captions appear below the image and with a limited width (instead of the caption occupying the whole width of the page), so they can be more easily distinguished from the rest of the text.

Does anyone know what commands/packages you need to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package? And are you familar with the LaTeX `minipage` environment? If so, you could place `\caption` directives inside `minipage` environments of suitably widths.